# Passing value from html table to input orm

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have an HTML table which get's updated through AJAX every 1 second.

```
   <div style="float: right;">
    <br><br>
<p style="padding-left:20px; font-size: 20px;">Amount(<?php echo $market; ?>) | Price(<?php echo $bm; ?>) &nbsp | Total(<?php echo $bm; ?>)</p>
<div class="panel-hello scrollbar" id="style-11">
    <div class="data-table">
        <table class="table table-buy table-bordered force-overflow" id="basiccubs">
            <tbody style="border: 1px solid green; height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll";>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And ajax :-

```
  function loadXML()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
   document.getElementById("basiccubs").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; // your div
   }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","get/buybtccpa.php",true); //your php file
xmlhttp.send();
}
window.setInterval(function(){
loadXML();
}, 1000);
```

There is html form as well

```
 <form name="myform" method="post" action="btccpa.php" style="float:left;">
    <div id="log_err"> <strong><?php if(isset($eroor)) { echo $eroor; } ?><?php if(isset($mint)) { echo $mint; } ?><?php if(isset($tm)) { echo $tm; } ?><?php if(isset($tah)) { echo $tah; } ?><?php if($au == 1) { echo 'Please log in to trade.';} ?></strong> </div>  
    <p>
        <label style="float: left;">Price:</label>
        <input class="input101" style="float: left;" type="text" name="uprice" id="box1" oninput="calculate()">
        <label style="float: right;">: <?php echo $market; ?></label>
        <input class="input101" style="float: right;" type="text" name="uam" id="box2" oninput="calculate()"><br>
        <input class="input101" style="float: right;" type="text" name="utam" id="result"><br><label style="padding: 10px;">Total <?php echo $bm; ?>:</label>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <input type="hidden" name="myform" value="1">
            <br><br>
            <span class="orderbutton" type="submit" id="orderbuy" onclick="myform.submit()">BUY</span>
        </td>
    </p>

</form>
```

And js to get value transferred from html table to form input onlclick.

```
  <script>

            var table = document.getElementById('basiccubs');

            for(var p = 0; p < table.rows.length; p++)
            {
                table.rows[p].onclick = function()
                {
                     //rIndex = this.rowIndex;
                     document.getElementById("box4").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                     document.getElementById("box3").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                     document.getElementById("resul").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;
                };
            }

     </script>
```

Without updating the html table every one second it used to tranfer values on click but now it's not. I don't see any problem in it but still not working. Values keep changing time to time.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to say, I'm not following you. But, you can check the console to see if any errors are showing either in your code or if your request's response is a valid one.

Comment: I want to pass data from html table to the input in form

Answer (score 0):

Use formData to upload for details to next page

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("username", document.getElementById("box2").value);
formData.append("accountnum", document.getElementById("box2").value);
```

paste it in

```
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

Comment: I need to pass from html table to form input

Comment: use documet.getElementById(inputid).value=documet.getElementById(tableclumnid).innerHTML

Comment: No answer? Please answer